# Sending pooled objects over eventbus

Tags: netty, vert.x

I have some expensive-to-create objects pooled in the Vert.x verticle and I'd like to send them to another verticle over eventbus. When I do so, is there a way (handler) to tell me that the object has been written down the line, so I can reset it and return to the pool?

In Netty (which is used in Vert.x) underhood the `ByteBuf`s get `retain()` called when these are no longer to be touched, even with async design. Is there anything similar I could use in Vert.x?

Answer (score 1):

going on what i know, i think the it depends on what makes the objects "expensive".

#### if the expensiveness can be attributed to the resources needed to compute its internal values, then the `EventBus`'s built in request-response messaging might be suitable

(...assuming the object isn't simply enormous and/or deeply nested)

on the sender `Verticle` side:

- grab the expensive object from the pool and compose a `Message` with it
- invoke a variant of `EventBus.send()` that accepts `Handler` for handling replies
- in the reply handler, return the object to the pool

on the receiver `Verticle` side:

- register a new `MessageConsumer` with the `EventBus` to receive messages from the sender
- when a new `Message` arrives, handle the expensive object, and then invoke some variant of `Message.reply()` to signal that the work on the receiver side is complete

#### if the expensiveness can be attributed to the size/complexity of the object, then shared data might be a better alternative to (de)serializing it over the `EventBus`

if you aren't familiar with the shared maps feature you can read up in the [docs](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_using_shared_data_with_vert_x).

going this route would be identical to the above approach with the following exceptions:

- instead of serializing the expensive object, stash it in the shared map
- send the associated key the object is stored at to the receiver `Verticle`

i'm not sure if there's a more framework-ready, idiomatic solution to your problem, but if nothing else i hope it inspires some new thinking.

Comment: Thanks, your first solution means that I could recycle the object as soon as I get reply. That's likely a viable solution, though I'd prefer to avoid the roundtrip-time, having just a marshalling handler (okay, I could probably hack something in the marshaller itself but I was thinking about an idiomatic solution).

Comment: when you say you'd like to avoid the roundtrip time, are you specifically referring to the cost of (de)serialization + the routing time? the latter i think is safe to assume is negligible, while the former really depends on the state of this expensive object instance. which goes to my second suggestion - if you believe the cost of (de)serialization to be high for your requirements, then try to avoid it.

Comment: also, what do you mean by "having just a marshaling handler"? not sure if you know, but you can indeed write + register your own `MessageCodec` with the `EventBus`. see the "Message Codecs" section of the docs at https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_the_event_bus_api

Comment: Roundtrip time to another physical computer can be milliseconds even on local network which is not negligible. I am not concerned about the CPU usage during serialization; in fact I am trying to keep very low allocation rates - that's why the object which can be serialized quite efficiently but has tens or hundreds of kilobytes (long sparse array) is pooled. I just want to return it to the pool ASAP (that means faster than in millisecond range).

Comment: Initially I wanted to register a handler that would be called (by Vert.x) after encodeToWire (which is synchronous), but in fact I could just let the implementation of the codec return the object to the pool. It's a bit hacky (codec should do marshalling and not anything else) but it would work in my case.

Comment: i'm a bit confused by the descriptions. you're looking for a handler to be triggered when "the object has been written down the line". i understood this to mean that the downstream work with the object has been completed, hence my answer. but with your latest comment it sounds like you just want to know that the downstream has been triggered, not necessarily completed. if so, why not simply just return the object to the pool after invoking `EventBus.send()` (or even `EventBus.publish()` since evidently a reply doesn't matter)? don't need a handler for that.

Comment: Ah, my expression 'down the line' could be really confused with 'downstream' - I meant writing bytes on the wire. I agree that it's also imprecise, I was following Netty analogy with ByteBuf too close. So now when we understand each other - is there a guarantee that EventBus.send() will do all the work synchronously? I can see various reasons why that would not be true: 1) network buffers are full and would block => the message gets queued 2) too deep recursion from the event loop thread => again queuing the send task 3) calling `EventBus.send()` from non-event-loop thread

Comment: no - an event bus is used for multicasting events to any number of consumers. it therefore delivers those events asynchronously for reasons of efficiency. the synchronous behavior i was referring to was the invocation of `send()/publish()` itself because you didn't seem concerned with the downstream processing of the event.

Comment: i'm now less confident i understand your needs. you were originally looking to register a handler (which by design are used to "handle" asynchronous operations) for returning an object to a pool, but are now inquiring about synchronous behavior. do you just want to serialize the object instance blockingly, and then `send()/publish()` the result downstream without any concern for what happens thereafter? if so, just invoke the serialization logic inline and then send the results over the bus. if not, i really don't understand what you're looking for.